# Is it possible to call a NodeJS service in a progress/openedge file?

Tags: node.js, openedge, progress-4gl

I was curious if its possible to call a node js service or file from a progress.p(complied is a .r) that runs on Linux?

Possible example something like this:

```
PROCEDURE callAdditionalCheck:
   FIND FIRST User NO-LOCK 
      WHERE USER.USERID = whateverUserVariable NO-ERROR.

   IF NOT AVAILABLE User THEN DO:
      /* Call Node service here. Service would run additional check here */
      NodeCheck(user,userInfo).

   END.

END PROCEDURE.
```

Things to note:

- Progress Openedge 11.3
- RedHat6

If there are other examples or possible resources I will gladly look at those too. I currently cannot find any. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to call a node-based REST-service or do you want to run a local node-based script/app or something else?

Comment: @Jensd I would like to ideally call an an API Rest service. It is easy to do the checks I need. Its for Active Directory. We already have an API for our new system so i really just want to use that one if possible or at least create a new using some of the things we do in our current node API.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066721/how-do-i-do-http-get-and-post-in-progress-openedge-abl/2070550#2070550

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do HTTP GET and POST in Progress/OpenEdge ABL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066721/how-do-i-do-http-get-and-post-in-progress-openedge-abl)

Comment: I'll have to play around some. This isn't exactly what I'm looking for but it could be an alternative. Thank you for you help so far!

Comment: @Jensd I would like to clarify the NodeJS service or file I would call would be an API call of sorts. An HTTP get/post call in Progress will not help me because of my current Linux draw issue that I'm trying to get around.

Comment: What kind of API? Apparently not a REST API then? SOAP? Shared object? A shell script? You need to specify more!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179394/discussion-between-anthonyfastcar-and-jensd).